# How do I accomplish the following with C# generics?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a generic `Result<T>` class and let's assume I have a `Handler<TRequest, TResponse>` interface and I want `TResponse` to be of type `Result<T>`.

how can implement the interface so it is close to the following example:

```cs
class HandlerImp<TRequest, TResponse> 
: Handler<TRequest, TResponse>
 where TRequest : Result<T>
```

the reason I want to be able to do this is I want to be able to return new `Result<T>` in the handler and I can not do that without knowing what the result type is.

Comment: If `T` is neither of `TReuqest` or `TResponse` type then you'll have to declare it as well: `class HandlerImp<TRequest, TResponse, TResult> : Handler<TRequest, TResponse> where TRequest : Result<TResult>`. Also, in order to `new` it up in method body, you'll have to add `where TResult : new()` as well

Comment: Did you mean `where TResponse : Result<T>`? You could also declare `class HandlerImp<TRequest, TResult> 
: Handler<TRequest, Result<TResult>>`.

Comment: Oliver the problem is with your method I need to be able to do:
           ```typeof(HandlerImp<, Result<>>)```
in order to be able to register the handler, but it's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve my problem in the following way:

```
    class Result
    {
        public IList<string> Errors { get; set; }
        public Exception Exception { get; set; }
    }

    class Result<T> : Result
    {
        public T Data { get; set; }
    }

    interface IHandler<TRequest, TResponse>
    {
        TResponse Handle();
    }

    class HandlerImp<TRequest, TResponse> : IHandler<TRequest, TResponse>
        where TResponse : Result, new()
    {
        public TResponse Handle()
        {
            return new TResponse()
            {
                Errors = new List<string>() { "This is an error" }
            };
        }
    }
```

It does not let me put the T Data but for my use case (ValidationHandler) it's great.